# com.android.volley.ServerError on Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

My application is very simple, Main Acitvity is just 4 buttons that go to the relevant activity, other 4 activities are for viewing, adding, updating, and deleting a product. i have a file called "AppController" where i have my connection 'defined', here is its code:

```
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;


//this is a singleton class where we initialize all volley core objects
public class AppController extends Application{
    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    public static String baseUrl= "https://example.000webhostapp.com/";  
/** Not the actual link */

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getmInstance(){
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){
        if(mRequestQueue == null){
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req){
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag){
        if(mRequestQueue != null){
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }

}
```

i have already made sure my server is working using Postman, i added a product using it, and it worked.

I have already checked other posts, and couldn't relate it to my code (I'm a bit of a newbie at android dev)

Comment: Way to go answering your own question Andrew! For the benefit of the community, it would be best if you can post your update as an actual Answer and not, simply, an update to your question. Cheers!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**UPDATE, i got it to work with the following code added to my AppController file at the end (just helping someone that might need it in the future)**

```
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                    if (response != null && response.statusCode == 404) {
                        try {
                            String res = new String(response.data,
                                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, "utf-8"));
                            // Now you can use any deserializer to make sense of data
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(res);
                            //use this json as you want
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                            // Couldn't properly decode data to string
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (JSONException e2) {
                            // returned data is not JSONObject?
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
```